# "ldap_start_tls: Can't Contact LDAP server (-1)" on Red Hat Linux 6.4

Tags: openldap

I have OpenLDAP working on a local development machine that is running Fedora 20.  I was able to install it and get it working fine for my own local testing.  I'm now trying to install OpenLDAP on a Red Hat 6.4 server and I'm running into a problem.  OpenLDAP on Red Hat won't be used for any outside connections.  It's just going to be used to have a simple LDAP server (with some dummy data) to talk to when running some of our continuous integration tests on the server.

The slapd service is starting fine.  OpenLDAP is listening on port 389 (but not 636).  When I execute:

```
ldapsearch -x -ZZ -h localhost
```

I get the following error:

```
ldap_start_tls: can't connect to LDAP server
```

I'm not really sure where to do next.  Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Is the RHEL server meant to be behind on its patches?

Comment: We were locked into a specific server at the time, but have since decided to upgrade RHEL 7 which solved our problem.